# Javascript: typeof says "function" but it can't be called as a function

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

I'm really puzzled with Javascript this time:

```
var x = Array.prototype.concat.call;
typeof x; // function
x(); // Uncaught TypeError: x is not a function
```

What on earth is going on here?

---

If it helps, I also noticed:

- `x([1,2],[3,4])` does not work either
- `toString` also thinks it's a function:

  ```
  Object.prototype.toString.call(x); // "[object Function]"
  ```
- This also happens with `Array.prototype.concat.apply`.
- When it is forced as an expression it also does not work:

  ```
  (0, Array.prototype.concat.call)([1,2],[3,4]); // Same TypeError
  ```

Tested in Chrome and Node.

Comment: `var x = Date.call;` is the same (or any handle to a methodical call); you're not _call_ ing it right.

Comment: This is just a mistake in the error message (the thing that’s not a function is `x()`’s `this`, not `x`). Firefox’s is correct, for example: “TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible undefined”

Comment: The [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) indicates that a `TypeError` should be thrown, but not what the particular message should be.

Comment: @Ry- Can you clarify? Note that `x([1,2],[3,4])` also does not work.

Comment: @Hamsterrific: `Array.prototype.concat.call === Function.prototype.call`. The important thing is how you call `call` – its `this` value determines the function that’s called. `x()` has a `this` value of `undefined`. `var x = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.concat);` was probably intended (but the error message is still wrong, and that would still be better as `var x = Array.prototype.concat.bind([])`).

Comment: Ah I just figured out as Ry was posting :-)

Comment: You've created an obscure syntax error by misusing prototypal inheritance. The way to look at this has _less_ to do with `call` than it does with `concat`. Concat is designed to return an Array object that `call` may then operate upon. But you've misused `concat` here by not giving it any input - which is required. This is the source of the error.

Comment: @Ry- Ohh I got it. Really nice. Can you please convert that comment in an answer?

Comment: `toString = Function.prototype.toString; toString()` -> `Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.toString requires that 'this' be a Function` It looks like the errors are inconsistent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The error is misleading. x *is* a function, but it has lost the referenced function (concat), which throws an error**

Running on firefox gives a more descriptive error

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Called_on_incompatible_type

What it's saying is that the `call` function has nothing its bound to.
In the same way that if you take an object like this:

```
const a = {
  b: 2,
  test() {
    console.log('hi', this.b);
  }
};
const c = a.test;
c();
```

You will get `hi undefined` as you've lost the relationship of the function to b.

You can fix this by either doing `c.bind(a)()` or `c.call(a)`

The `call` function behaves similarly. It is going to be the same for *every* function, and the pseudocode would look something like this:

```
class Function {
  constructor(functionDefinition) {
    this.functionDefinition = functionDefinition;
  }

  call(newThis, ...args) {
    // take this.functionDefinition, and call it with `this` and `args`
  }
}
```

Since you are extracting out the call function, it loses the function object it's associated with.

You can fix this by either binding concat to the function, or using call on call :-)

```js
const a = []
const boundFn = a.concat.call.bind(a.concat)
console.log(boundFn([3], [1,2]));

// Or, you can use `call` to pass in the concat function
const callFn = a.concat.call;
console.log(callFn.call(a.concat, [4], [1,2]))
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it now, thanks to your answer and especially Ry-'s comment above. Suggestion: you could emphasize that the call function is the same for every function, and what is important is the call's `this` (I know you already said it briefly but that was the crux for me and I think it could be said more explicitly) :)