# Illegal invocation on window['document']['body']['append'] function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

(I think) I have tried every `.bind` , `.call()` or `.apply` version,

But I can't make `F2("World!")` work

```js
var F1 = window["document"]["body"];

// works fine:
F1["append"]("Hello")

var F2 = F1["append"];

// valid function append() 
console.log( F2 );

// Illegal invocation
F2("World!");
```

Would like to get it working in:

```js
let D=["document", "body", "append"];
([0,1,2].reduce((root, x) => root[D[x]], window))('World!');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50421102/4135063

Comment: Indeed, and plenty more duplicates once you know what you are looking for. I first waded thru plenty jQuery 'Illegal Invocation' posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`F1["append"]` is only a reference to `Element.prototype.append`:

```js
var F1 = window["document"]["body"];
var F2 = F1["append"];
console.log(F2 === Element.prototype.append);
```

This function requires a calling context - a `this` value - in order for the function to know what the parent element is, to which the child will be appended to. With

```
F1["append"]("Hello")
```

The object on which the function is called is `F1`, the `this` value that the function sees, so everything works as expected. But with

```
F2("World!");
```

There is no calling context - the function being called is not called as part of an object, and the function hasn't been bound, so the internal `Element.prototype.append` doesn't know which parent element the child should be appended to.

`.bind` works, as does `.call`, as does making a function which calls `F1` with the proper calling context:

```js
var F1 = window["document"]["body"];

// works fine:
F1["append"]("Hello")

var F2 = F1["append"];
F2.call(F1, "World!");
```

```js
var F1 = window["document"]["body"];

// works fine:
F1["append"]("Hello")

var F2 = child => F1["append"](child);
F2("World!");
```

To do this with `reduce`, first `.pop` off the last property. Then use `reduce` to get to the next to last property (the object on which the function should be called on). Then you can call the function with the required calling context via bracket notation:

```js
const paths = ["document", "body", "append"];
const fnProp = paths.pop();
const lastObj = paths.reduce((parent, nextProp) => parent[nextProp], window);
lastObj[fnProp]('World');
```

Comment: tnx, slowly getting it....See the reduce snippet I added. So that means I do have to check inside my reduce loop with ``Element.prototype[x]`` ? But how then keep it generic so I can also use a *dictionary* which also has ``[....,"customElements","define",...]`` those are not in the Elements.prototype.

Comment: Cool. I now understand.TNX!. I have some work to do to make ``[[0,1,2,"Hello"],[0,1,2,"World"]]`` work.. I was just on the wrong track to make it work with a single String ``0,1,2,Hello,0,1,2,World`` and ended up in recursion hell because I hadn't expected that Illegal Invocation